# Dataframe withColumn function

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I know general structure of how to use withColumn function with a DataFrame like

```
df = df.withColumn("new_column_name", ((df.someColumn > someValue) & (df.someColumn < someOtherValue)))
```

Lets say, now, that the operator information (> and < in the above example) is stored as string(inputted by user). How can I perform above kind of operations? One naive way I can think of is to write many if else blocks one for each kind of operation and whenever we want to add new operation then we would have to add more if else blocks.

What obvious tweaks am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think it would be possible. The Scala DSL wouldn't be able to compile and understand without the operator. One way would be as you say to define a match function with many cases. Relevant post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371475/convert-string-into-operator-in-scala

Comment: `assert op1 in ["<", ">", "="]  and  op2 in ["<", ">", "="];  df.select(pyspark.sql.functions.expr("someColumn {} someValue AND someColumn {} someOtherValue".format(op1, op2)))`?

Comment: I went ahead and tested it. This works fine for the "select" part. But how can I use it in withColumn. I have tried something like `new_df = df.select(expr("metric.duration {} 0.5 AND is_activity {} False as query".format(">", "="))); df = df.withColumn("query_two", new_df["query"])`. But, it gives an error `/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in withColumn(self, colName, col)
   1312         """
   1313         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
-> 1314         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
   `